# How can i solved this error: app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses Failed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dagger-hilt

My error:

> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)

I was try to fix it by changing in build.gradle (Project)

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false`

to

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false`

but I got this error:

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and
> 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 18) jvm target
> compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

The errors starts showing when i try to setup Dagger-Hilt in my project.

I upload project to github, because I don't know which files I should share: https://github.com/DawidSiudeja/WordlePL

***EDIT***
I add in build.gradle dependencies:

```
constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

and another errors :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use a compose compiler library which is not compatible with your kotlin library in 1.8.0

you can follow the documentation here to solve for future cases: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

[image]

Steps to fix: (Acording to kotlin library 1.8.0)
You must need to change la compose compiler to 1.4.0 or 1.4.1

open your build.gradle and look for composeOptions then change the current version for the compatible version:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Now i getting this error: "Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 18) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version."

Comment: I delete 2 dependecies and it start working now

Comment: @xMaster, which dependencies you have delteted to solve the problem?

Comment: try to check the compatibily options, as you can see the error xMaster Had, you must try to change in that case to VERSION_18: compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }